# MySql, assign variable to non existent field (Hardcoding a value as a column value)

Tags: mysql

I'm not sure if this is possible or not, but for example in this case:

```
SELECT 
  i.name 
FROM
  items i 
  INNER JOIN users u 
    ON u.item_id = i.id 
  INNER JOIN sales s 
    ON s.item_id = i.id 
WHERE u.status = 1 
  AND s.status = 1
```

I would like to assign non existing field to "type", so if records belong to "users" table type = Users, otherwize type = Sales.

it should look something like:

```
|        name | type  |
|-------------|-------|
|  First Item | User  |
| Second Item | Sales |
| Second Item | User  |
```

Comment: The Inner join work only on full match so you can't get the result you showed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this might be what you're trying to do.

```
SELECT i.name,'User' as type FROM items i 
    INNER JOIN users u ON u.item_id = i.id WHERE u.status = 1
UNION
SELECT i.name,'Sales' as type FROM items i 
    INNER JOIN sales s ON s.item_id = i.id WHERE s.status = 1
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c81bf/2

Inner Join items with users and hardcode 'User' as type

Inner Join items with sales and hardcode 'Sales' as type

Then UNION the 2 selects together.

Comment: Thanks, your solution partially works, in your sql fiddle, there should be 4 records showing instead of 3.

Comment: Ignore my previous comment, All I needed was UNION ALL, and it works perfect. Thnak you so much.

Comment: UNION ALL would work too but I thought since one you're hardcoding results from one table to be 'User' type and another results from one table to be 'Sales' type, they should never merge together so UNION would work like a UNION ALL in anycase UNION ALL would work yeah..